# Why is my react/express proxy acting weird?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

If I set the proxy to "http://localhost:8080/api" in package.json and stick "api" at the front of my routes, everything works. If I leave api off, nothing works - I get status 404s. The tutorials I've seen don't include "/api" at all. I'd rather not stick "api" on all of my routes.

This gives status 200 -

package.json -
  `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/api"`

server index.js -

```
`app.get('/api/ping', function(req, res) {
  res.send('(◍•ᴗ•◍)❤ pong');
});`
```

This gives status 404 -

package.json -
  `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

server index.js -

```
`app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
  res.send('(◍•ᴗ•◍)❤ pong');
});`
```

Comment: you can create a custom rule to map `/api` to `/` using `setupProxy.js` (assuming you're using create-react-app). what's wrong with adding `/api` in your backend? you can always use an express router so you only have to write that once

Comment: Thanks, azium. I guess there isn't really a problem. Turns out it's just confusion on my part about what api means. I've always seen it as just a way to get some json data back from a db, but now that I look at the definition, I realize it means "a way of accessing data & features of another service". I tend to get hung up on naming things and, in my arrogance, assumed that I knew what api means.

Comment: you're not alone, api is an extremely vague and overloaded term. the DOM ships with a DOM api, there's the `Math` api etc, there are 3rd party json apis that serve over http. feel free to use a different name. call it `/server` if you want